# Kernel panics from Spotify

Tags: kernel-panic, kernel, spotify

Lately, I keep getting kernel panics, with the report indicating that the culprit is the Spotify desktop app. I'm on a 2014 iMac, with huge amounts of RAM and free space, and I've done a hardware test and found nothing.

Today, I reinstalled the Spotify desktop app, but that didn't help. (If anything, the kernel panics now seem more frequent.)

I did find some old posts about Kernel panics from Spotify, and that Apple was working on a solution, but clearly whatever they cooked up didn't work.

Is there anything else I might try?

EDIT: Here is the log I get after restart. As discussed above, it does not show up anywhere under /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports, merely in the "Your computer restarted because of a problem" report right after I turn the machine back on.

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801251264a): "Invalid waitq: 0"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/kern/waitq.c:5581
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa0af17b6a0 : 0xffffff80124bab4d 
0xffffffa0af17b6f0 : 0xffffff80125fd7e3 
0xffffffa0af17b730 : 0xffffff80125ede1a 
0xffffffa0af17b780 : 0xffffff801245fa2f 
0xffffffa0af17b7a0 : 0xffffff80124ba3ed 
0xffffffa0af17b8c0 : 0xffffff80124ba6d8 
0xffffffa0af17b930 : 0xffffff8012cbef9a 
0xffffffa0af17b9a0 : 0xffffff801251264a 
0xffffffa0af17b9e0 : 0xffffff8012a1818c 
0xffffffa0af17ba70 : 0xffffff8012a1ec4f 
0xffffffa0af17bab0 : 0xffffff8012a30ad1 
0xffffffa0af17bc20 : 0xffffff8012a38f8e 
0xffffffa0af17bca0 : 0xffffff8012a383d1 
0xffffffa0af17bf40 : 0xffffff8012b698cb 
0xffffffa0af17bfa0 : 0xffffff80124601f6 

Process name corresponding to current thread: Spotify

Mac OS version:
20D91

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000012200000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8012400000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000012210000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8012410000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012300000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-FA842E06C61E91C5)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 25259355671918
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000016f926ec10ad
  Sleep   : 0x00000a347a9bb7e0 0x0000000063d17296 0x0000088f7f0d91ee
  Wake    : 0x00000a34820c5555 0x0000000064554601 0x00000a34810916d9
last started kext at 24351392722476: >usb.!UUserHCI 1 (addr 0xffffff7fb2d9f000, size 102400)
last stopped kext at 24482589873183: >usb.!UUserHCI 1 (addr 0xffffff7fb2d9f000, size 102400)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   119
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.2
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.2
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.2
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 16.0.1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    16.0.1
>eficheck   1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@kext.AMD9000!C 4.0.2
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
>!ASDXC 1.9.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 346
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AHIDKeyboard  223
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4030.5
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4070HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.2
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    930.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
|IONDRVSupport  585
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
|IOGraphics!F   585
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   294
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: Please share two or more panic reports with us (they can be found in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`). You can use www.PasteBin.com.

Comment: Strange, I don't see any panic reports there. I see FinderSYNCAPIExtension crash reports, but none of the reports that pop up when the computer restarts. (I always select "Report", fwiw.) Could they be somewhere else? In particular, none of what I *do* see seems to implicate Spotify, the same way the onscreen report does. (It says something like, "Thread responsible: Spotify".)

Comment: You don't see any files with file extension `.panic` or `.ips` in either `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` or `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Retired`? When was the last time you had a panic?

Comment: I don't. All I see is .crash and .diag. The panics almost always happen overnight, while Spotify is just idling in the background and not playing. But today, they happened several times while I was watching, listening to music. I had one within the past hour. I could probably produce one right now if I opened up Spotify. I can copy and paste the report that comes up after restart, if that helps?

Comment: That would help!

Comment: @pion Just added the report. Sorry it took me a while. Would appreciate any insights you might have!

Comment: We need to see the backtrace. This requires enabling symbolication. Can you disable SIP, run `sudo nvram boot-args="kextsyms=1"`, reboot, and collect & upload a new panic report?

Comment: @pion Well, I can, but the problem is, I can't find the panic report on my machine. Only in the error dialogue box right after restart. Could they be stored somewhere else? Otherwise, I guess I can do all the things you suggest and just wait for another panic, or will that not work?

Comment: Yep that's what I'm meaning. (I am still not sure why the panic reports aren't getting saved to /L/L/DR...)

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks! (Might be a few days. These things happen at odd intervals.)